Different thermald settings for battery and AC
I use thermald to prevent my Surface Pro 7 from overheating, using the intel powercap rapl driver (rapl_controller in thermald). I would also like to use the same rapl driver to reduce power consumption when on battery, but I can't find a way to do that aside from copying and pasting into the terminal each time:
sudo systemctl stop thermald && sudo powercap-set intel-rapl -z 0 -c 0 -l 5000000 -s 12000000 && sudo powercap-set intel-rapl-mmio -z 0 -c 0 -l 5000000 -s 12000000

Is there a way to get thermald to change the TargetState for the rapl_controller to 5000000 when on battery?
Here is my current thermal-conf.xml for reference:
<ThermalConfiguration>
<Platform>
        <Name>Surface Pro Intel Thermal Workaround</Name>
        <ProductName>*</ProductName>
        <Preference>QUIET</Preference>
        <PPCC>
                <PowerLimitMaximum>16750</PowerLimitMaximum> <!-- milliwatts -->
                <PowerLimitMinimum>4000</PowerLimitMinimum>
                <TimeWindowMinimum>12000</TimeWindowMinimum> <!-- milliseconds -->
                <TimeWindowMaximum>12000</TimeWindowMaximum>
        </PPCC>
        <ThermalZones>
                <ThermalZone>
                        <Type>cpu</Type>
                        <TripPoints>
                                <TripPoint>
                                        <SensorType>x86_pkg_temp</SensorType>
                                        <Temperature>67000</Temperature> <!-- thousandths of a ºc -->
                                        <type>passive</type>
                                        <ControlType>SEQUENTIAL</ControlType>
                                        <CoolingDevice>
                                                <index>1</index>
                                                <type>rapl_controller</type>
                                                <SamplingPeriod>1</SamplingPeriod>
                                                <TargetState>12750000</TargetState> <!-- microwatts -->
                                        </CoolingDevice>
                                </TripPoint>
                        </TripPoints>
                </ThermalZone>
        </ThermalZones>
</Platform>
</ThermalConfiguration>

EDIT:
I ended up creating a systemd service to check the battery status every minute and run the relevant command. I'd still be interested to know if it's possible through thermald.
